# Largest molecules verified in a Miller Urey experiment

Tags: experimental-chemistry

What are the largest molecules confirmed with confidence in a Miller Urey experiment?

I know the experiment can create amino acids (which are mostly <250Da) and nucleotides (which are mostly <350Da). However, I see some papers suggesting molecules even in the 800-1000Da range.

Is it true such large molecules can form in the experiment? And, if so, what types of molecules are they typically?

Thank you.

Comment: There might not be a rigorous upper bound. There's been many variations on the experiment, but the sludge they tend of form ("[thiolin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tholin)") often contains complicated polymeric molecules.

Comment: Thank you, Nicolau! So, in your opinion, it is not *too rare* for large >600Da (or even >800Da) molecules to form in the Miller Urey?

Comment: It's certainly possible. It's useful to have to keep in mind that *you generally find what you are looking for*, and it's typically easier to detect and characterize smaller molecules (especially ones we already know, or others similar to them). Larger molecules generated under these conditions are probably extremely varied and structurally chaotic, and even though their collective amount may add up to a substantial fraction of the sludge, each individual substance will be present in very low abundance, so they may end up ignored.

Comment: I suspect running high-resolution mass spec measurements on the sludge could give a so-called "forest" of weak signals at higher molecular weights, though I haven't read the articles to confirm it.